# Change default for Nautilus (file_manager) from "Forget password immediately"?

Tags: password, samba, nautilus

When opening a tab which needs to mount a Samba share, [Nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager%29) 2.30.1 displays a window:

```
Password required for share xxx on localhost

Password: [           ]

(*) Forget password immediately
( ) Remember password until you log out
( ) Remember forever

               [Cancel] [Connect]
```

How can one set the default to something other than "Forget password immediately"?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the default to "Remember password until you log out" was filed as a [GNOME bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587909). The [fix](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=3094265abbfd3b70b39bb1dbd9625a81faf0fbca) went into the mainline in July 2010, and was part of GNOME 2.31.5, so if you update you should get this behavior automatically. As far as I can tell from [this comment](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587909#c5), it's still not user-configurable, but at least you'll have a more useful default