# Nemo: Forget encryption password

Tags: security, password, nautilus, nemo

I have mounted an encrypted disk by selecting it in Nemo (1.1.2), then typing a password.  I can unmount the disk using Nemo, but now it can be remounted without requiring the password.

Probably there was a "remember" option such as demonstrated [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7294/change-default-for-nautilus-file-manager-from-forget-password-immediately).

Regardless of what I selected when I initially mounted, now **I want Nemo to forget the password**.  Is there a way to do this aside from logging out?

*This question may also apply to Nautilus (Nemo is a fork).*

Comment: Note: I was hoping that there would be a nice way to do this from a GUI, but I have searched Nemo's menus, system settings, and the "Seahorse" Passwords and Keys utility -- all to no avail.

Comment: I went years without this bothering me, but it got me again in Ubuntu MATE 18.04.  Although, I think it is called `caja` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really mean "forget the password" it probably already did within microseconds of you entering it.

Persistence of authentication through the login session is maintained in Ubuntu-ish systems by `ssh-agent` and `gnome-keyring-daemon`. By their nature of operation (non-invertable hashing) it may be fundamentally impossible to selectively remove one authentication.

As you note, logging out destroys the cached authentication, `ssh_agent -k` would kill the cache without logging out (but other things would fail to authenticate too).

This looks like you can have single-sign-on ease or fine-grained authentication control, pick one.

Comment: "forget the password" is probably not technically correct, but it agrees with the message provide (see [the link in my question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7294/change-default-for-nautilus-file-manager-from-forget-password-immediately)).

Comment: I had no luck with `ssh-agent -k`, but the following did work: `killall gnome-keyring-daemon`.  Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the following, or something equivalent...

```
killall gnome-keyring-daemon
```

Comment: [It's amazing the variety of issues that can be resolved by: `killall gnome-keyring-daemon`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280800/398660)

Answer (score 0):

The program seahorse is a nice graphical way to manage passwords including the nemo disk encryption passwords (in the menu it is "passwords and keys").
Under "Passwords" - "Login" you will find the saved passwords for encryption and network drives. you can delete, change or view passwords.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post & this is old so i don't know if this applies:
Nemo hard coded "G_PASSWORD_SAVE_FOR_SESSION" as default when asking for passphrase
to get around this, compile it from source and replace "G_PASSWORD_SAVE_FOR_SESSION" with "G_PASSWORD_SAVE_NEVER"

(this took me forever to figure out, because i dont know c and i am new to linux and compiling stuff)